# absolute div in div with overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a tab menu that sits on the bottom of a div and when a tab link is clicked it slideup with it's content.

Here is what I've got so far. I really can't see why it's behaving they way it is
http://jsfiddle.net/5mVt8/11/

The key bits:

```
#content {  
  position: relative;  
  width:500px;  
  height:400px;  
  overflow:hidden;
}
.page {
    position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:380px;
  width:500px;
  height:400px;
}
```

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="page" id="one"><a href="#one">Click</a>Page 1</div>
  <div class="page" id="two"><a href="#two">Click</a>Page 2</div>
  <div class="page" id="three"><a href="#three">Click</a>Page 3</div>
</div>
```

Full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/5mVt8/11/

Is these a bug with having a absolute positioned div inside a relative div with overflow? Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work or how I should approval this?

Comment: You should say what the bug is.

Comment: Looks fine. How did you expect it to behave?

Comment: It wasn't animating, (sliding).

Comment: The div are not sliding up. Div #page3 simply jumps on top of the rest and higher than it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have #content fixed height with `overflow:hidden` and pages on the bottom partially hidden with this overflow. Now on link click anchor works and #content *scrolls down* to the hidden block top. You should add `return false` at the end of click event function to prevent default behavior.

Also you have missed the [animate method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) syntax. It should be like this

```
$(this).parent().animate({'top': '0px'}, 300, "swing");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5mVt8/27/

Comment: Also I made css-animation version for you http://jsfiddle.net/5mVt8/32/ that requires only class changes in js :)

Comment: CSS would be better, but still not totally supported, so he'd need a javascript fall back anyway. I love CSS animations, but still not there.

Comment: Leeish, it is only IE less than 10 that not support css animation now http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20transition, on some projects you can drop some effects in IE.

Comment: I feel ya. But anyone who is dumb enough to use IE, most likely won't be upgrading. I'm just saying CSS is the better solution, but to be correct, he'll still need a javascript fall back.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the #one #two #three from your html.

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="page" id="one"><a href="#">Click</a>Page 1</div>
    <div class="page" id="two"><a href="#">Click</a>Page 2</div>
    <div class="page" id="three"><a href="#">Click</a>Page 3</div>
</div>
```

Now simply write your animate correctly.

```
 $('.page a').click(function(){ 
     $(this).parent('.page').animate({top:0}).addClass('open');
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5mVt8/18/

EDIT: I am sure you could find a cleaner way to write your CSS. All those absolutes and positioning and z-indexes. I would find a better way to accomplish what you want, but that's me.

Comment: That works great, thanks. My main error was in the animate property.

Comment: I am not even sure why, but when i leave the text in there, it won't animate. Strange, but it is what it is.